# URL button to prepopulate values in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button, urlhacking

I am trying to replace a URL button used in a list view in Classic to Lightning Compatible. I am trying to open a lightning component through URL that fires the create new page of the object with prepopulated values. The lightning component is like below

Component

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable"  >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
 doInit : function(component, event, helper){
   var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
     var record_Id = 'XXXYYYZZZZ';
     var alert = 'Test';

   createRecordEvent.setParams({ 
     "entityApiName": "Inventory__c", 
                       'recordTypeId': record_Id,
    "defaultFieldValues": {
      'alert__c' : alert
    } 
  });
  createRecordEvent.fire(); 
 }
})
```

I created the URL button and have the URL like `/lightning/cmp/c__createInventory` where createInventory is the lightning component name, when clicking on the button it navigates to the blue screen nothing is happening no errors / no create new page getting fired. Can anyone please help me here what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigating to a lightning component via a URL button will work in these scenarios:-

### Approach 1

You can generate a URL where you pass Base64 encoded object of component definition:-

```
var compDefinition = {
    componentDef: "c:createInventory",
    attributes: {        
    }
};
// Base64 encode the compDefinition JS object
var encodedCompDef = btoa(JSON.stringify(compDefinition));
console.log('/one/one.app#' + encodedCompDef);
```

The log prints the following value:- `/one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJjOmNyZWF0ZUludmVudG9yeSIsImF0dHJpYnV0ZXMiOnt9fQ==`

You can then make use of this URL in your URL button.

### Approach 2

Create a lightning app page and add your component there. Now simply navigate to lightning app page from the URL button using App Page URL.

```
/lightning/n/pagename
```

---

Comment: in Approach 1, where Should I add the lightning component definition, Is it with the lightning component itself?

Comment: you don't need to add component definition, you just need to add the URL generated using component definition in the url button.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a release issue and actively worked upon.  Kindly review [Known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003wWZQAY) and try workaround mentioned.  Also, take a look at [URL hacking for lightning](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm).

Thanks,